# How do I create an outcome quiz using html and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to create a quiz and all the examples of quizzes I can find are scored mathematically with numerical values set for each answer. This is my attempt to create a "What ____ are you?" outcome quiz. What am I missing to make this work or how can I fix this code to make it more efficient? Thanks.

Edit: The problem is that it doesn't display a result after submission.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Title Of Quiz
</TITLE>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
Title of Quiz
<!--Quiz itself will go here-->
<form action="/results" method="post">


<!--This is where the questions go-->
<b>Question 1<br></b>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="a" VALUE="1">answer choice 1<br>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="a" VALUE="2">answer choice 2<br>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="a" VALUE="3">answer chocie 3<br><br>

<b>Question 2<br></b>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="b" VALUE="1">answer choice 1<br>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="b" VALUE="2">answer choice 2<br>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="b" VALUE="3">answer choice 3<br><br>

<b>Question 3<br></b>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="c" VALUE="1">Answer choice 1<br>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="c" VALUE="2">answer choice 2<br>
<input TYPE="radio" NAME="c" VALUE="3">answer choice 3<br><br>

<input id ="submit" type="submit" value="Get Result!" onclick="return process();"><br><br>
</form>

    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
 function process()
{
var result1 = 0;
var result2 = 0;
var result3 = 0;

var f = document.f;
var i = 0;

<!--This is where the question values go-->
   for (i = 0; i < f.a.length; i++) if (f.a[i].checked) value = f.a[i].value;
if (value == "1") { result1++; }
if (value == "2") { result2++; }
if (value == "3") { result3++; }

  for (i = 0; i < f.b.length; i++) if (f.b[i].checked) value = f.b[i].value;
if (value == "1") { result1++; }
if (value == "2") { result2++; }
if (value == "3") { result3++; }

  for (i = 0; i < f.c.length; i++) if (f.c[i].checked) value = f.c[i].value;
if (value == "1") { result1++; }
if (value == "2") { result2++; }
if (value == "3") { result3++; }

var out = "result1";
i = result1;

if (result2 > i) { out ="result2"; i = result2; }
if (result3 > i) { out ="result3"; i = result3; }
location.href = out + ".shtml";
}
function err(msg, url, line)
{
location.href = "error.html";
}
 
</SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: So you've dumped some code here and stated a general goal. But how does this code not meet your needs? Specifically, what does it do wrong?